# Postfix: deleting emails with recipient not in virtual_alias_maps

Tags: postfix

I'm getting a lot of spam for recipients that don't exist on my domain. I'm forwarding email on this domain to various external addresses for my family by using virtual_alias_maps.

To prevent these invalid addresses cluttering up my mailq and just generally being annoying I'd prefer to delete them if they can't be matched to a specific recipient.

A previous question said I could potentially use

```
bounce_queue_lifetime = 0
```

but that if I'm using virtual domain/users I should use virtual_mailbox_maps. Unfortunately I can't see how to achieve this as all examples for the opposite which is default delivery for all addresses e.g @example.com delivered to user "jim"

One option would be to do default delivery to  /dev/null 
e.g. @example.com to user "devnull" then create an entry in /etc/aliases for devnull to /dev/null. Is this a valid approach?